# Error results if I try to call string data from a Channel

Tags: c, user-interface, go, github, window

I am trying to write a program that is supposed to fetch a bunch of data from an RSS link (that part works), and then store it in a GUI window. However, my code shows the GUI window for about a millisecond, then gives me this error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
main.(*modelHandler).CellValue(0xc0000e81b0, 0xc0000760e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8, 0xc00004c380)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/FinalProject/GUI-Based System.go:71 +0x517
github.com/andlabs/ui.pkguiDoTableModelCellValue(0x9ba820, 0x17ba1b0, 0x0, 0x4047a0)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/github.com/andlabs/ui/tablemodel.go:171 +0xc3
github.com/andlabs/ui._cgoexpwrap_7d4d3b498194_pkguiDoTableModelCellValue(0x9ba820, 0x17ba1b0, 0x0, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:4087 +0x7f
github.com/andlabs/ui._Cfunc_uiControlShow(0x3977350)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:1624 +0x48
github.com/andlabs/ui.(*ControlBase).Show.func1(0x3977350)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/github.com/andlabs/ui/control.go:108 +0x5d
github.com/andlabs/ui.(*ControlBase).Show(0xc000394380)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/github.com/andlabs/ui/control.go:108 +0x36
main.setupUI()
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/FinalProject/GUI-Based System.go:131 +0x2b2
github.com/andlabs/ui.pkguiDoQueueMain(0x0)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/github.com/andlabs/ui/main.go:103 +0xb0
github.com/andlabs/ui._cgoexpwrap_7d4d3b498194_pkguiDoQueueMain(0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:3967 +0x32
github.com/andlabs/ui._Cfunc_uiMain()
    _cgo_gotypes.go:2519 +0x48
github.com/andlabs/ui.Main(0x8037a8, 0x77e420, 0xc000048920)
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/github.com/andlabs/ui/main.go:41 +0x104
main.main()
    C:/Users/Owner/go/src/FinalProject/GUI-Based System.go:151 +0x1b7

Process finished with exit code 2
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "github.com/andlabs/ui"
    _ "github.com/andlabs/ui/winmanifest"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

type JobInfo struct{
    Title string `xml:"title"`
    Location string `xml:"location"`
    PostDate string `xml:"pubDate"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Channel struct{
    Title string `xml:"title"`
    Link string `xml:"link"`
    Desc string `xml:"description"`
    Items []JobInfo `xml:"item"`
}

type Rss struct {
    Channel []Channel `xml:"channel"`
}

type modelHandler struct{
    row9Text string
    yellowRow int
    checkStates [10000]int
}

func replace_weird_characters(s string) string{
    reg, err := regexp.Compile("&nbsp;|<[a-zA-Z /]+>")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    new_string := string(reg.ReplaceAllString(s, " "))
    return new_string
}

func newModelHandler() *modelHandler {
    m := new(modelHandler)
    m.row9Text = "You can edit this one"
    m.yellowRow = -1
    return m
}

func (mh *modelHandler) ColumnTypes(m *ui.TableModel) []ui.TableValue {
    return []ui.TableValue{
        ui.TableString(""),
        ui.TableString(""),
        ui.TableString(""),
        ui.TableString(""),
        ui.TableString(""),
        ui.TableColor{},
        ui.TableColor{},
    }
}

func (mh *modelHandler) NumRows(m *ui.TableModel) int {
    return 10000
}

func (mh *modelHandler) CellValue(m *ui.TableModel, row, column int) ui.TableValue {
    new_rss := Channel{}
    if column == 0{
        return ui.TableString(new_rss.Items[row].Title[:strings.LastIndex(new_rss.Items[row].Title," at ")])
    }
    if column == 1{
        return ui.TableString(new_rss.Items[row].Location)
    }
    if column == 2 {
        company := new_rss.Items[row].Title[strings.LastIndex(new_rss.Items[row].Title, " at "):strings.LastIndex(new_rss.Items[row].Title, " (")]
        real_company_name := strings.Replace(company, " at ", "", -1)
        return ui.TableString(real_company_name)
    }
    if column == 3 {
        postdate := strings.Replace(new_rss.Items[row].PostDate, "Z", "", -1)
        return ui.TableString(postdate)
    }
    if column == 4 {
        real_description := replace_weird_characters(new_rss.Items[row].Description)
        return ui.TableString(real_description)
    }
    panic("unreachable")
}

func (mh *modelHandler) SetCellValue(m *ui.TableModel, row, column int, value ui.TableValue) {
    if row == 9 && column == 2 {
        mh.row9Text = string(value.(ui.TableString))
    }
}

func setupUI()  {
    mainwin := ui.NewWindow("something", 640, 480, true)
    mainwin.OnClosing(func(*ui.Window) bool {
        ui.Quit()
        return true
    })
    ui.OnShouldQuit(func() bool {
        mainwin.Destroy()
        return true
    })

    mh := newModelHandler()
    model := ui.NewTableModel(mh)
    table := ui.NewTable(&ui.TableParams{
        Model: model,
    })

    mainwin.SetChild(table)
    mainwin.SetMargined(true)

    table.AppendTextColumn("Title",
        0, ui.TableModelColumnNeverEditable, nil)

    table.AppendTextColumn("Location",
        1, ui.TableModelColumnNeverEditable, nil)
    table.AppendTextColumn("Company",
        2, ui.TableModelColumnNeverEditable, nil)

    table.AppendTextColumn("Post Date",
        3, ui.TableModelColumnNeverEditable, nil)
    table.AppendTextColumn("Description",
        4, ui.TableModelColumnNeverEditable, nil)

    mainwin.Show()
}

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?l=Bridgewater%2c+MA%2c+USA&u=Miles&d=100")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    rss := Rss{}

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    err = decoder.Decode(&rss)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    ui.Main(setupUI)
}
```

I have determined that it results in an error when I'm trying to do things like

```
new_rss.Items[row].Location
```

However, I'm not sure how to turn it back into a regular string.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling .Items[row].Title (and others) on a brand new Channel struct - something in that code is incorrect, as any row value here will cause an error like that...
(As the Items are uninitialised)

Comment: Instead of calling new_rss.Items, I decided to call Channel{}.Items. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error.

Comment: How do you suggest I initialize the Items array? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to pass the “rss” object that you parsed into to your UI code one way or another. The simplest (but dirty) way would be to make that variable global, then use “rss.Items” instead of “new_rss.Items”.